# Is Python3 safe from DST changes that may be coming?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, unix-timestamp

**Background**

I've been unable to find a deeper explanation of the real source of the time value used by Python. Most of the documentation states that it 'gets the value from CPython' but does not go into detail about where it comes from beyond that point.

Some countries have recently changed or are looking to change their DST policies. This means that devices in those countries may auto-adjust the time zone and produce an incorrect GMT-based time until they are updated with the current policies.

That's not terrible on it's own, because operating systems usually have a great mechanism for updates. However, updating Python on those same systems is a very murky area sometimes. The OS may handle it, or perhaps Python is bundled with the application. Perhaps the OS is still getting critical updates but not Python updates.

**The Problem / Question**

We do not control how Python is being updated with our code. The concern is that we may get an incorrect unix-time-stamp from Python due to the GMT time calculation being out-of-date.

If Python delegates the GMT time calculation to the OS, then we can rest easy. If Python does not delegate it, then we may have to force the value to come from the OS (e.g. time+%s).

*So the question is: Does Python3 get it's GMT time from the OS or from it's own calculation based on local time?*

Comment: Is it possible for a piece of software to get the time from anywhere that doesn't ultimately rely on either the OS or some server knowing the (correct) time?

Comment: Yes. For Java, they have classes that allow you to get a TimeZone / ZoneInfo object for a location such as "Europe/Moscow" and then that object has methods that deal with DST like useDaylightTime().   Thankfully, it seems Python does not do this, per Zachary's answer.    

Java fortunately also has a tool to update the definition ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/troubleshoot/time-zone-settings-jre.htm ) but for our scenario its better to get that from an OS update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does not keep its own database of timezone information; it delegates to the OS and/or the [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) third-party package for all timezone-related calculations.  UTC or local timestamps are fetched from the OS via the C `gmtime_*()` and `localtime_*()` functions from the platform's `time.h`.

For the full story in source, have a look at the [Python version](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py) of the datetime module, the [C version](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_datetimemodule.c) of the same, the [time module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/timemodule.c), and the [pytime.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pytime.c) C module.

Comment: So the C library looks to be "time.h" with gmtime_r for non-windows and gmtime_s for windows.   As long as we just call gmtime in Python then we should be able to avoid pytz issues? Because it looks like pytz can be a liability in this scenario due to needing to support offline timezone conversion + being based on the Olson tz database.

Comment: Right; clarified where the C functions come from in an edit.  As for pytz, remember that it's a third-party package; if you don't install it and use it, it won't affect you anyway.